# How to refresh data in treeview in TKInter

Tags: python, sql, tkinter, treeview, updating

i've been looking and editing my code for the last 48 hours to work out how to refresh my data from a database in a TKInter, however it will only add further duplicates. I've searched all over the internet and it's not what I am looking for and I'm quite new to using Python/TKInter.

Below is what i've got at the moment, this just duplicates records. I need them to update automatically using the TKInter.after function.

```
from tkinter import ttk
import tkinter as tk
import pyodbc


def View():
    con1 = pyodbc.connect(r'Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};DBQ=C:\Users\craig\UKDN\DB.accdb;')
    cur1 = con1.cursor()
    cur1.execute("select * from Units")
    rows = cur1.fetchall()

    for row in rows:

        print(row)
        tree.insert("", tk.END, values=row)

    con1.close()
    root.after(1000, View)



root = tk.Tk()
tree = ttk.Treeview(root, column=("c1", "c2", "c3"), show='headings')
tree.column("#1", anchor=tk.CENTER)
tree.heading("#1", text="ID")
tree.column("#2", anchor=tk.CENTER)
tree.heading("#2", text="FNAME")
tree.column("#3", anchor=tk.CENTER)
tree.heading("#3", text="LNAME")
tree.pack()
View()
root.mainloop()
```

I've researched and edited the code multiple times, at the moment the code just duplicates the records in the database.

Comment: You can use the `Treeview.item()` method to update items that already exist in the `Treeview`

Comment: Have you got an example to do that?

Comment: `for iid in tree.get_children(): tree.item(iid, values=(new, values, here))` - do this after you've `insert`ed the items

Comment: Unfortunately, that duplicates the first record multiple times in loop.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out... something so simple of

```
for i in tree.get_children():
    tree.delete(i)
```

Adding this before the loop code starts works.